# Run event over socket

Tags: reactjs, sockets, events

I use a file for get socket response, then i navigate response to other files.

**For example:**

```
import socket from 'socket.io-client';
import { ShowModal } from '../components/Modal';

socket.on('message', function(data){
     ShowModal(data);
})
```

But every time i get following error:

**Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component**

How can fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is:

"**Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component**"

in your case, its mean use `<ShowModal />`  on your app file. then ShowModal most have following content:

**EG:**

```
import socket from 'socket.io-client';

class ShowModal extends Component {
    _isMounted = false;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }
    modal(data){
     if(this._isMounted){
          // Your Codes
     }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this._isMounted = true;
        socket.on("message", data => this.modal(data));
    }
    render(){
        // Put Your codes
        return (
            <>
            </>);
    }
}


export default ShowModal;
```